# Set Batch Command Line As String Within Another Command Line

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

As the title Suggests, I'm Trying to Set a command line output as a string within another command line.

Example:

> verpatch %%~ni%%~xi  /s desc %%~ni /s comment %%~ni /pv **'call jrepl
> "[0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]+" "" /match /s %filename%'**

Please note that:

```
call jrepl "[0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]+" "" /match /s %filename%
```

is another command which outputs: **1.2.3.4** [It's a function that extracts numbers from a file name]

So I need this output to like this:

verpatch %%~ni%%~xi /s desc %%~ni /s comment %%~ni /pv 1.2.3.4

Here I share my entire code so you get the idea:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
set file=C:\Users\Jack\Desktop\Files\*
set dot=.
FOR %%i IN ("%file%") DO (
set filedrive=%%~di
set filepath=%%~pi
set filename=%%~ni
set fileextension=%%~xi
:: This Line is supposed to store jrepl command as a string ::
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
SET COMMAND="call jrepl "[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+.[0-9]+" "" /match /s %filename%"
:: Extract the string and print to the screen
verpatch %%~ni%%~xi  /s desc %%~ni /s comment %%~ni /pv %COMMAND%
pause
)

pause
```

**jrepl** is regex text processor batch functions file [**JREPL.BAT**](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6044) by dbenham

This is My Second Attempt to save the command to line in as a variable:

```
@ECHO OFF
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "file=C:\Users\Jack\Desktop\Files\*"
FOR %%i IN ("%file%") DO (
set filedrive=%%~di
set filepath=%%~pi
set filename=%%~ni
set fileextension=%%~xi
: Save Command Line as a variable
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('call jrepl "[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+.[0-9]+" "" /match /s %%~ni') do @set theValue=%%a 
verpatch %%~ni%%~xi  /s desc %%~ni /s comment %%~ni /pv %theValue%
pause
)
pause
```

I have a folder full of my personal programs

> ProgramOne 1.2.3.4.exe
>
> ProgramTwo 2.2.2.2.exe
>
> etc.

and I'm trying to make a batch that extract Program name and Version from those programs and have them inserted into individual command lines, for example:

verpatch "ProgramOne 1.2.3.4.exe" /s desc ProgramOne /s comment ProgramOne /pv 1.2.3.4

Comment: I would expect `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` and change `%COMMAND%` to `!COMMAND!` and also enclose your `set`ting in quotes. i.e. `set "file=C:\Users\Jack\Desktop\Files\*"`

Comment: Thank you Gerhard!! But, unfortunately I'm getting "error parsing version arg
bad version arg, see usage (/?)"

Comment: there would be more to do, let me see if I have time to go through your code quick.

Comment: Do not use double colons for comments inside a code block.

Comment: `/pv` expects a product version string not a command. You'll need to run the command first, get its output as a variable and use that instead. Also `%%~ni%%~xi` can be shortened to `%%~nxi`.

Comment: @Compo That seems logical! However, this is what I get when I did `ERROR: Too many arguments.
  Use JREPL /? or JREPL /?? to get help.`  I used  `for /f "delims=" %%a in ('call jrepl "[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+.[0-9]+" "" /match /s %%~ni') do @set theValue=%%a`

Comment: @Squashman I don't think that's an issue because i removed them and exact same result

Comment: I have updated my question with a second attempt where the variable is returning an empty string.

Comment: In your new attempt, you need to use the delayed expansion version of the variable, `/pv !theValue!`

Comment: @MrJackMcfreder, it will cause errors but wasn't your main problem.  You didn't really say you were trying to capture the output of JREPL and put it into a variable.  You just said you were trying to assign the command as a string.  This isn't bash. You can't assign output of commands directly to a variable like you can with BASH.

Comment: Do you think you need to use JREPL to accomplish this task?  If you could show us examples of your input file names maybe we could simplify the process for you.

Comment: @Squashman, Good Idea! I have updated my post again. Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, *I'm assuming that both your `verpatch` and `JREPL` commands are correct, (I've never used them)*:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "filelocn=C:\Users\Jack\Desktop\Files"
For %%A In ("%filelocn%\*.exe") Do (For /F %%B In (
        'jrepl "[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+.[0-9]+" "" /match /s %%~nA') Do (
        verpatch "%%A" /s desc "%%~nA" /s comment "%%~nA" /pv %%B
        Pause))
```

**Edit**

Based on your provided filenaming strategy and without using `JREPL` this may work for you:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "filelocn=C:\Users\Jack\Desktop\Files"
Set "progName="
For %%A In ("%filelocn%\*.exe") Do (SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    For %%B In (%%~nA) Do If Not Defined progName (Set "progName=%%B"
    ) Else Set "fileVer=%%B"
    verpatch "%%A" /s desc !progName! /s comment !progName! /pv !fileVer!
    EndLocal)
```

Comment: Tried your suggestion but I am getting the command prompt empty ready to take input: https://image.prntscr.com/image/im2qqnYgR12yyytLbM72MA.png

Comment: Remove `@Echo Off`, we'll need to see the output!

Comment: @MrJackMcfreder, as your now provided filenames include spaces, I have modified the first code by surrounding the names with doublequotes. Additionally I've added an **Edit** to attempt the same task without `JREPL`.

Comment: Thank You Very Much Compo!  The Second bloc works like charm!

Comment: You can edit `For %%A In ("%filelocn%\*")` To `For %%A In ("%filelocn%\*.exe")` so the batch would not return an error and stop processing if encounters other filetypes.

Comment: @MrJackMcfreder, I have edited it accordingly, and made a modification to the **Edit** such that your `/desc` and `/comment` match the program name only.